# How to fill entire ImageView with a icon?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, android-relativelayout

I have an `ImageView` in `RelativeLayout`. Problem is my icon is not filling all the space in the `ImageView`. Its padding inside from all the direction. I found some solution and tried every possible combination, but its not changing a bit. My icon regulation `256*256`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="109dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <ImageView
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:background="@drawable/iconforalbumgrid"
            android:id="@+id/albumCover"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <TextView
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:id="@+id/albumName"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/albumCover"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/albumCover"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/albumCover" />

        <TextView
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:id="@+id/textView55"
            android:layout_below="@+id/albumName"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/albumCover"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/albumCover" />

        <TextView
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="Small Text"
            android:id="@+id/textView56"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/albumCover"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/albumCover"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/albumCover" />


    </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Can u check if the image doesn't have a transparent area around the icon

Comment: Thanks a lot. You are right. It was transparent problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are having the transparent area around the image.
 You have to use an updated image without a transparent area

Answer (score 1):

Inside your ImageView, add this:

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```